# MySQL master slave

Tags: mysql, master-slave

We are trying to replicate MySQL Master Slave. My master (MySQL version 5.6) and slave (Mysql version 8. x). We replicated master and slave with the same versions, But we didn't try with different versions. Is it possible to replicate it? If yes, Foreign key names longer than 64 characters are no longer supported by MySQL 8.0. So What is it doing for those foreign keys.. will it drop them?

Comment: 5.6 is no longer receiving updates, including security updates so consider it insecure and upgrade as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

You can replication from one release series to the next highest (5.7 to 8.0 okay, 5.6 to 8.0 nope) but be careful as older behaviors may not be supported.